# How do I calculate the standard deviation of interval (binned) data in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

How would I calculate the standard deviation of the interval frequency data below using pandas?

```
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks([105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 130, 135])
df = pd.DataFrame({"Bin": idx, "Frequency": [2,5,6,8,8,1]})
df
```

Additionally

- how do I calculate the mean of this interval data?

Comment: Well, how do you define the standard deviation? Does it make sense to get the std of the frequency? probably not

Comment: What are you exacrtly trying to do? `df['Frequency'].std()` will give the standard deviation of the frequency column.

Comment: Correct I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculating the standard deviation of the frequencies probably doesn't make sense.

You probably want the standard deviation of the bins.
You could estimate a range using the lower and upper boundaries:

```
# getting left and right boundaries
left = df['Bin'].map(lambda x: x.left)
right = df['Bin'].map(lambda x: x.right)

low  = np.sqrt(np.cov(left, aweights=df['Frequency']))
high = np.sqrt(np.cov(right, aweights=df['Frequency']))
```

*NB. here it's the same as all intervals have the same step.*

`(low, high)`:

```
(7.375021006356025, 7.375021006356025)
```

##### mean

```
low = np.average(left, weights=df['Frequency'])
high = np.average(right, weights=df['Frequency'])
```

`(low, high)`:

```
(118.0, 123.0)
```

##### alternative: using the mid-point of each interval

```
mid = (left+right)/2

std = np.sqrt(np.cov(mid, aweights=df['Frequency']))
avg = np.average(mid, weights=df['Frequency'])

print(f'{avg.round(2)} ± {std.round(2)}')
```

Output: `120.5 ± 7.38`

Comment: For the record, the exact right way to handle this problem is to treat the frequency data as interval-censored data, and compute a maximum likelihood estimate for the censored data. Taking the midpoint of each interval and weighting by frequency is a good approximation; taking either the left or right endpoint doesn't really make sense, since effectively what is needed is to average over all possible values in the bin, and the extremes of the bin aren't good approximations of that. Incidentally for the MLE I get mean = 120.4996, s.d. = 6.3797. I think the midpoint approximation is good enough.

Comment: @Robert thank your for your valuable input, indeed the min/max might drift a lot with high frequencies. Would you suggest a specific method? [`scipy.stats.CensoredData`](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.stats.CensoredData.html)?. This min/max approach was a response to the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77384505/1) in which OP computed the `std` of the frequencies.

Comment: On reading the documentation, looks like CensoredData is relevant, but not exactly on the mark, since each CensoredData value represents exactly one observation; what's needed is censoring plus being able to assign an arbitrary weight (proportional to the bin mass in the current problem) to a censored value. Without weighting, you could approximate the result by duplicating an interval censored value a number of times proportional to the bin mass. That's an unnecessary complication, it's better to keep looking, I think.